How to get correct figure references when a quarto child-document is rendered multiple times?
The issue here is that when repeatedly using child documents with figures/tables all references are to the last version of the figure/table in the document/site. My question: is there is any way to help quarto figure out which figure/table should be referenced?
I set up a github repo to make a minimum reproducible example, since it's too much code to dump here. Just clone the repo and run quarto render.

Details:
I have a quarto book project that uses the knitr engine. It conducts an analysis on several different days of data. To do this I have a quarto document for each day with parameters in the YAML header, e.g.,
params:
  date: "2024-08-28"

In the body of the document I have
```{r}
options(knitr.duplicate.label = "allow")
```

```{r child='day-template.qmd'}
```

I generate a book (HTML or PDF) using quarto render. There is a chapter for each day, and the day-template.qmd analysis executed for each chapter. The problem is that even though I'm allowing duplicate labels, the figure references using those labels are not correct.
E.g., if there is a code chunk in day-template.qmd that generates a plot with the label fig-a. I can reference that figure in the body of day-template.qmd using @fig-a. However if day-template.qmd is creating content for chapters 2 and 3, then the @fig-a reference that is in chapter 2 will reference the version of the figure in chapter 3.
Here is what it looks like when rendered to PDF:

Is there a way to help quarto figure out how to properly configure figure labels in this case?
